# Encapsulation and Inheritance in Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, encapsulation

In Javascript you can get inheritance through object prototypes or you can have encapsulation via a closure that returns an interface object to the bits you want to expose. Is there any way you can have both simultaneously? If so, what would be a good way to go about it?

Comment: An example of what you want, and what you think you can't get, would dramatically improve/clarify this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
function Base(thing) {
    this.getThing = function() {
        return thing;
    };
}
Base.prototype.cappedThing = function() {
    return this.getThing().toUpperCase();
};

function Derived(thing) {
    Base.call(this, thing);
}
Derived.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype);

var d = new Derived("foo");
console.log(d.cappedThing()); // "FOO", through inheritance and encapsulation
```

But if the question is **really**: Does JavaScript have anything like "protected" in various class-based languages (methods available to "subclasses" but not when you directly instantiate the base class), then the answer is no, it doesn't. You can get close if the base and derived are defined in a shared, but otherwise private, scope, and even more so when ES6's [`Name` objects](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3aprivate_name_objects) are commonplace, but nothing that spans completely independent compilation/scope units.